# Checkbox causes incorrect height on parent element

Tags: css, google-chrome, checkbox

I am trying so solve a problem that causes me and my colleagues a splitting headache. Even though we've been provided a painkiller each we continue to be baffled by the way Google Chrome renders a checkbox in a container that has a `font-size` of `10pt`.

## The problem

Google Chrome seems to render some extra space around a checkbox element that I cannot seem to get rid of. The checkbox and its parent element **must** be `15` pixels tall. Setting the font-size of the parent element to 10pt causes that parent element to be `16` pixels in height.

## An example

Take a look at the snippet below.

I have yet to find out (or understand) what causes the checkbox element to render as 15 pixels tall but effectively making its parent element 16 pixels tall.

```css
td,
th
{
    padding: 0;
    font-size:   10pt;
}

input[type=checkbox]
{
    height: 15px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="data">
    <tr>
        <th>Label 1</th>
        <td>Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Checkbox 2</th>
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Label 3</th>
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

<sup>Exchanging the table for a `div`, a `p` or any other container also results in an incorrect height for that container.</sup>

## Possible solution?

Setting the checkbox height to `14px` makes the parent row `15` pixels tall. But then the checkbox itself does not meet the designer's requirements and thus this solution will not be accepted. Any workarounds?

Comment: Change `display` type of checkbox to `block`?

Comment: Actually, `input` has a default `font` property. If you add `font-family: sans-serif` to `td`, it seems to correct the discrepancy.

Comment: To the person asking to close the post for "unclear what you are asking": what exactly is unclear about my question? If you'd engage in conversation I could improve my post.

Answer (score 1):

`input` has default `font` property:

`font: 13.3333px Arial`

If you ensure that both the input and text in adjacent cells are the same font it should remove differences in line-height (I think).

Also, add `display: block` to `input`

```css
td,
th {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  height: 15px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="data">
  <tr>
    <th>Label 1</th>
    <td>Value 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Checkbox 2</th>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Label 3</th>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using `display: block`? We want to avoid making the element float when text or other elements have to be near.

Comment: @BobKruithof I can't find a way to get the same appearance without it. I'm not sure I understand what problem `display: block` introduces - could you elaborate?

Comment: if that element has the `display` property set to `block` then any text next to that element needs to be wrapped in a container for positioning. So instead of `[input element] foo bar apple orange` it would mean `[input element][container]foo bar apple orange[/container]`

Comment: @BobKruithof Updated my answer.. I hope I've understood your comment correctly! If I haven't, maybe you could update your question with an image of what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you, but if you look at my first comment you'll see I'm trying to avoid floating. The previous version of your answer did provide an adequate solution so if you revert it I can accept that as an answer.

Comment: @BobKruithof Ok, sorry I don't think I'm quite getting the different scenarios you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

First, add `display: block;` to the `input`.

You can change the parent behaviour with the `box-sizing` property.

```
td {
   box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

should fix your problem.

```css
td,
th {
   padding: 0;
   font-size:   10pt;
}
    
tr {
   box-sizing: content-box;
}
    
input[type=checkbox]{
   display: block;
   height: 15px;
   border: none;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="data">
    <tr>
        <th>Label 1</th>
        <td>Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Checkbox 2</th>
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Label 3</th>
        <td><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem in 2020, on Chrome and Firefox, and none of the solutions here worked. This is what worked for me

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    height: 21px;
    vertical-align: top;
    position:relative;
    top:-5px;
}

.checkboxcontainer{
    max-height: 16px;
}
```

In my case we had a structure

```html
<div>
    <div data-x="lots of these" />
    <div data-x="lots of these" />
    <div data-x="lots of these" />
    <div>
        <div class="checkboxcontainer">
             <input type="checkbox" ...>
```

And the outer div was being given a huge top margin. Deleting the checkbox in f12 confirms that the checkbox was the culprit, and the css provided seemed to work ok